# Why is the subject treated as a plural when it is written as an "either ... or"?

Tags: grammatical-number

This sentence appears in Donna Leon's Acqua Alta, Chapter 20:

> »War Monsieur Bernadotte oder seinem Teilhaber denn zuzutrauen, daß **sie** wissentlich Fälschungen **verkauften**?« fragte Brunetti.

Google translates this as:

> "Was either Monsieur Bernadotte or his partner likely to knowingly sell fakes?" Asked Brunetti.

But why does this sentence treat the subject as plural when it is either ... or? Should it not be written

> »War Monsieur Bernadotte oder seinem Teilhaber denn zuzutrauen, daß **er** wissentlich Fälschungen **verkauftet**?« fragte Brunetti.

What about with entweder? Is it still treated as a plural?

> »War entweder Monsieur Bernadotte oder seinem Teilhaber denn zuzutrauen, daß sie wissentlich Fälschungen verkauften?« fragte Brunetti.

Comment: _**verkauftet**_ is wrong, should be **verkaufte**. Otherwise regarding to your question I am probably a bit too _native german blind_ to spot what's exactly your problem or concern.

Comment: Could it be, that your conception is that the plural declension of _verkaufen_ refers to _Fälscungen_, rather than _Monsieur Bernadotte_ and his _Teilhaber_? In one case both persons are addressed as a whole (=> plural), in the other a particular person of the two is addressed (=> singular).

Comment: What I was trying too say was that I don't see the point of including an English translation and then talking about the translation instead of the original.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich You would have written "Waren ... und ... zuzutrauen, daß sie ... verkauften"? This would be wrong since *dass sie verkauften* (alternatively, *es*) is the subject of *jmdm. zuzutrauen sein*. Examples: _**Es war ihnen** zuzutrauen_, but _die **Taten waren ihm** zuzutrauen_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or (oder) can without further context be treated as inclusive (A and/or B) or exlusive (either A or B, but not A and B). The way "or" is parsed depends highly on context and sometimes remains ambigious.

> "War Monsieur Bernadotte oder seinem Teilhaber denn zuzutrauen, dass sie wissentlich Fälschungen verkauften?", fragte Brunetti.

Since it's in 3rd person plural, this is an inclusive or, meaning either Bernadotte or his associate or BOTH, were selling fakes.

> "War Monsieur Bernadotte oder seinem Teilhaber denn zuzutrauen, dass sie wissentlich Fälschungen verkauften?", fragte Brunetti.

3rd person singular implies it's an exclusive or, so either Bernadotte OR his associate sold fakes.

Since *either ... or* implies an exclusive or, 3rd person singular is the only valid option. Otherwise you'd get a conflicting sentence.