# Singular relative pronoun as a choice referring back to two different gendered pronouns

Tags: relative-pronoun

If you have multiple singular nouns with different genders and want to use a relative clause to choose one of them, which do you use?

> Es war egal, ob es der Mann oder die Frau war, (?) ihr helfen wollten/wollte.

I've seen question pronouns used where in English you would not. Is this an appropriate place for "[...], wer ihr helfen wollte."?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the subject treated as a plural when it is written as an "either ... or"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/59543/why-is-the-subject-treated-as-a-plural-when-it-is-written-as-an-either-or)

Comment: By the way, the sentence should read "Es war egal, ob der Mann oder die Frau, (?) ihr helfen wollten/wollte."

Comment: Is there a verb missing in the *ob*-clause?

Comment: Thank you and almost answers it but not quite, unless I missed something. My example is exclusive 3rd person singular but the choice of relative pronoun is either der or die, not known at the time of utterance. So which do I choose, or can I go with the more neutral wer to maintain the possibility of either?

Comment: @ David Vogt yes there was.

Comment: @tom: Can you please reference & distinguish yours from the not so duplicate question?

Comment: @ Shegit Brahm: I will try, When a relative singular pronoun is an unknown choice that will occur, of a set of nouns/pronouns with different genders, then what gender should the pronoun take?

Comment: The not so duplicate question above was  "War Monsieur Bernadotte oder seinem Teilhaber denn zuzutrauen, daß sie wissentlich Fälschungen verkauften?« fragte Brunetti." This shows the relative pronoun as being plural to encompass the set of two (masculine) nouns. In this example, the 'or' could be interpreted as either one, or both; whereas my example excludes both and the relative clause must refer simultaneously to two singular nouns of different genders.

Comment: A native speaker would sidestep the issue. Something like "Es war egal, ob der Mann oder die Frau ihr helfen wollen würde."

Answer (score 4):

By principle, the relative pronoun must match the positionally **closest noun** in gender and number if nouns are connected alternatively (e.g., by *oder* -- the case of all nouns should be the same anyway):

> Der Mann oder die Frau, **die** ihr helfen **wollte**, war es (Caveat: intentional deviance in meaning. See below!)

However, there is a complication in your example: the relative pronoun would need to refer to *es*. A relative pronoun referring to *es* in a construction like '... ist es, der/die/das ...' where *es* is a so-called *Subjektprädikativ* must match the actual subject:

> **Der Mann** war *es*, **der** ihr helfen wollte
>
> **Die Frau** war *es*, **die** ihr helfen wollte

This is why the sentence I gave above would at least in my opinion have a different meaning. The sentence

> Es war egal, ob es der Mann oder die Frau war, die ihm helfen wollte.

would rather transform to

> Die Frau, die ihr helfen wollte, war es *(und nicht der Mann oder eine andere Frau)*. [NB: *es gewesen sein* means like 'to have done it' in this sentence]

than to

> Der Mann war es, der ihr helfen wollte *(und nicht die Frau)*.

from my point of view. I think this arguable though.

---

#### What remains as 'work-around'?

One could say:

> Es war egal, ob es der Mann oder die Frau war, der oder die ihm helfen wollte.

...or simplify the sentence:

> Es war egal, ob der Mann oder die Frau ihm helfen wollte.

*Wer* or *das*, however, cannot be used as relative pronoun here.

Comment: The final work-around is in my opinion the best, simply rearrange the clauses to avoid this apparent paradox. Would the second clause not be ", ob der Mann oder die Frau ihm helfen wollten." because it is now definitely plural? The inclusive workaround (der oder die) makes sense and works technically but I find it clumsy.

Comment: @ amadeusamadeus: the beginning of your answer is, in my opinion, a bit confusing. "By principle, the relative pronoun must match the closest noun in gender and number if nouns are connected alternatively " By closest do you mean the order in which they appear, so the relative pronoun would match the last noun in the list?

Comment: Also it seems as though you alluded to the best answer of all without actually mentioning it. "Es war egal, ob es der Mann oder die Frau war, das ihr helfen wollte." or perhaps "Es war egal, ob der Mann oder die Frau es war, das ihr helfen wollte." This then fulfills the principle of last mentioned noun in a set and allows for the possibility of either gender being correct. Would this very last sentence be acceptable to a native German speaker (or in formal writing)?

Comment: @tom (1) If you have an alternating conjunction like *oder*, the subject is considered to be singular and so must be the verb. Only cumulative conjunctions like *und* go with the plural. (2) Yes, 'closest' refers to the position in the sentence, so usually the last noun of an enumeration. (3) That's not possible/ungrammatical. I explicated the reason in the second paragraph of my answer: "A relative pronoun referring to *es* in a construction like '... ist es, der/die/das ...', where *es* is a so-called *Subjektprädikativ*, must match the **actual subject**" (see above for examples).

Answer (score 2):

Native speakers seem to have no trouble interpreting a phrase of the form *X or Y* as a plural, which means the chosen relative pronoun is *die* and the verb in the relative clause is plural as well. Some examples from the [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/r) corpus:

> "Jede Klasse", bemerkt Schumpeter mit einer einleuchtenden Metapher, "gleicht während der Dauer ihres Kollektivlebens … *einem Hotel oder einem Omnibus*, **die** zwar immer besetzt **sind**, aber von immer anderen Leuten"
>
> Der hatte ihm mittlerweile schon so etwas wie Frieden beschert, *eine Linderung oder eine Lösung*, **die** stärker **waren** als der Bann, den man über ihn verhängt.
>
> Man sieht kaum *einen Mann oder eine Frau*, **die** nicht irgendein Hakenkreuzabzeichen **tragen**.

> Soll durch *eine Anzeige, einen Antrag oder eine Willenserklärung*, **die** in fremder Sprache **eingehen**, zugunsten eines Beteiligten eine Frist gegenüber der Behörde gewahrt, ein öffentlich-rechtlicher Anspruch geltend gemacht oder eine Sozialleistung begehrt werden, **gelten** *die Anzeige, der Antrag oder die Willenserklärung* als zum Zeitpunkt des Eingangs bei der Behörde abgegeben

(Note that, in the last example, the main clause subject *die Anzeige, der Antrag oder die Willenserklärung* is itself interpreted as a plural, as the verb form *gelten* shows.)

> So **werden** *ein Arzt oder ein Anwalt*, **die** sich in einer kleinen Stadt **niederlassen**, natürlich ihren daselbst seßhaften Kollegen einen Besuch abstatten.
>
> wonach *eine Organisation oder ein Individuum*, **die** im Sinne des Gesetzes öffentlich als kommunistisch erklärt **wurden** und gegen diesen Vorwurf **appellieren**, nicht die Beweislast zu tragen **haben**
>
> *Ein Regenwurm oder ein Tintenfisch*, **die** im Leben glatte Formen **besitzen**, **sinken** zusammen, wenn mit dem Tode die Muskeln erschlaffen

(In the three examples above, the phrase the relative clause is referring to is also the subject of the matrix clause, with the finite verb in the plural.)

> Bei sehr rauhem Wetter wählt *ein Mann oder eine Frau*, **die** nicht gerade seefest **sind**, den besseren Teil der Tapferkeit und bleibt möglichst allein.

(This one is interesting in that the verb in the main clause is singular, yet the relative clause referring to the subject of the main clause shows plural.)