# How do adjectives decline with multiple, mixed-gender nouns?

Tags: adjective

If I wanted to say "a free car, dog and cat" would

> "ein kostenloses Auto, Hund und Katze"

work?  or would I have to split it up and say

> "ein kostenloses Auto, ein kostenloser Hund und eine Kostenlose Katze"

since they have different genders and decline differently?

Comment: Related [question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/60635/singular-relative-pronoun-as-a-choice-referring-back-to-two-different-gendered-p).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In correct German, you would indeed have to split it up to make the adjective refer to all the nouns:

> "... ein kostenloses Auto, ein kostenloser Hund und eine kostenlose Katze ..."

Of course, repetition like that is just bad style. So to avoid that, you would normally use a workaround like an apposition:

> "... ein Auto, ein Hund und eine Katze, alle (drei) kostenlos, ..."

Comment: It can be bad style, or it can be used to emphasize (even with same gendered nouns)